# Simulate instrumental variables in R

Tags: r, instrumental-variables

I have run into this piece of R code that simulates a strong instrumental variable Z in the relation between X and Y.

```
U<- MASS::mvrnorm(1000, c(20, 15), matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2))
Xprime <- U[, 1]
C <- U[, 2]
Z <- rnorm(2000)
X <- Xprime + Z
Y <- 1 + X + C + rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
```

If now I would like to modify the code to show how a flawed instrument affects the relation, I know I should modify Z so that is is not exogenous anymore. My question is, how could I alter the code to make Z endogenous?

Comment: You have two options. Either you add $Z$ to the equation generating the outcome or you separate out the unsystematic variation in the outcome (u<- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)) and allow it to affect $Z$. You might want to do that and allow it to affect $X$ too, because as it stands, $X$ is exogenous and IV is not needed to recover its coefficient, 1.

Comment: I was also thinking about the first option, but regarding the second one, how would that actually look in code?